# Can I find which parameters are "pre-assigned" in python?

Tags: python, arguments, inspect

If I have a function or a method, can I find which parameters are "pre-assigned?" E.g. If I write

```
 def action(one, two, three=3): pass
```

can I get list of the parameters that have an assignment operator in them? In this case, of course it would be

```
 ['three']
```

I *think* the answer may lie with `inspect`. `inspect.getargspec(action)` is *really* close as it returns a tuple of the default arguments, but it doesn't say to which parameter each argument belongs.

Comment: The default values have to belong to the last arguments sequentially (as mentioned in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`inspect.getargspec()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec):

> *defaults* is a tuple of default argument values or None if there are no default arguments; **if this tuple has *n* elements, they correspond to the last *n* elements listed in *args***.

Emphasis mine.

So, to match your defaults to the arguments, use:

```
dict(zip(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):], argspec.defaults))
```

to get a dictionary mapping argument names to their defaults:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def action(one, two, three=3): pass
... 
>>> argspec = inspect.getargspec(action)
>>> dict(zip(argspec.args[-len(argspec.defaults):], argspec.defaults))
{'three': 3}
```